# Which Champion is the AD best carry?

Tags: league-of-legends

Hey I need help figuring out which champion is best in the AD carry spot.  I currently play Tristana and Corki, but would love to switch to someone new.

Comment: Hi @Angelik, your question was closed as Not Constructive because it is asking for opinion and speculation. Questions like this often end up devolving into "list of X" questions, where people up/downvote *champions* they like/dislike rather than whether or not the *answers* are high/low quality, which is an abuse of our voting system. As a Q&A site, we focus on trying to have a single, high-quality answer for a question, and considering the number of AD carries, there's no single, best answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Kog'Maw, though he may be very squishy (like most AD carries) he can just mow down tanks and pretty much anyone if you are fed enough.

Comment: Yeah Kog'maw looks pretty sweet, especially because of his late game shredding potential.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend caitlyn if you want to try someone new and fun.  Pair her up with alistar for a pop up into slam dunk onto your trap.  Plus, her ult is fun while laning.  She has tons of range, the net for escaping, and a nice way to clear a minion wave with her peacemaker.

I also like graves, quickdraw is just a ton of fun for dodging skillshots and suprising enemies in your tornado.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "best" per say. They all have certain things they all do well. Cait and Trist have range. Graves and Vayne have damage. Kog has both, but a very difficult early game. Of course there are more.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Tristana and Corki that you like, then you're probably use to having an escape or engaging mechanic so you should find something like that such as Shaco or Caitlyn. Other than that, it's all a matter of preference, since there is no 100% "Best Champ" for any role like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say, I however must say late game it is 100% ashe! Her ult will stun her opponent and she will destroy them before they are out of the stun. That being said i must underline that this is late game ashe, she tends to not do as well as cait, vayne, or graves early game.

I am saddened however that i think people forgot about that AD carries don't have to be range. Master Yi is the most unstoppable AD carry when he is in late game his speed and attack speed get Penta Kills like no other champion besides karthus.